# Creating a GUI on ubuntu for software written in C

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, user-interface

I'm doing a sniffing project and almost done with it. We are now planning to create a GUI for it. We have written the entire network programming project in C language on Ubuntu 10.10 platform. Any idea/tools with tutorials regarding how to create a GUI for these C programs?
Will the language/tool/platform used for creating the GUI affect the C source code?
Thank you

Answer (score 3):

There are different libraries for creating GUI applications in Linux.

There is [GTK+](http://www.gtk.org), which is the native widget toolkit for GNOME and which has a C API. There is also [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/products/) which has a very good C++ API, and which is also available for Windows, Mac OS X and other platforms.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest using GTK+ . It was natively written in C so compatibility shouldn't be an issue. I used [this](http://zetcode.com/gui/gtk2/) to help me learn it when i was messing around with it.